# How can I swap 2 digits (i,j) from a n number?

Tags: java

basically i have an integer n = 23456 and i want to swap the second and fourth digit, so i = 2 and j = 4. So the output would be 25436. I can´t use any Java class, so I supose that one of the ways to do it is by divide the number on powers of 10 and keep the rest on a new variable.

this is what i have so far:

```
public static int powerOfTen(int n) {
    int p = 10;
    while(n-1 > 0) {
        p = p*10;
        n--;
    }
    return p;
}

public static int swapNum(int n, int i, int j) {
    int swap = 1;
    int count = numDigits(n);
    int digit1 = nDigit(n, i);
    int digit2 = nDigit(n, j);
    
    if(i > j) {
        swap = n/powerOfTen(i);
        int rest = n%powerOfTen(i);
        rest = rest/10;
        swap = swap*powerOfTen(i);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this program do?  What is wrong with it?  Can you provide some examples?

Comment: @markspace im trying to swap two digits (i,j) from the int n, considerating that i and j are  positions of n

Comment: @markspace sorry about that mate, it's my first time using stackoverflow, but no it is not working, as it's writen on the description I said it's what I have so far

Comment: OK, I don't understand what you're asking.  Is something going wrong with your code?  Does it give you errors?  Does it give you the wrong output?  Can you give an example of what it's doing wrong?  What actual help do you need here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code with some modifications:

```
public class Main
{
    // Count the number of digits in an integer
    static int numDigits(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0) return 1;
        int count = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            count++;
            n /= 10;
        }
        return count;
    }
    
    // Reverse an integer
    static int reverseNumber(int n)
    {
        int result = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            result = result * 10 + n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    // Get the nth digit - from the left
    static int nDigit(int n, int index)
    {
        n = reverseNumber(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            n /= 10;
        }
        return n % 10;
    }

    static int swapNum(int n, int i, int j)
    {
        // Make indexes 0-based
        i = i - 1;
        j = j - 1;
        
        int count = numDigits(n);
        int digit1 = nDigit(n, i);
        int digit2 = nDigit(n, j);

        int result = 0;
        for (int k = count - 1; k >= 0; --k) {
            int digit;
            // Get the correct digit, i, j, or current
            if (k == i) digit = digit2;
            else if (k == j) digit = digit1;
            else digit = n % 10;
            result = result * 10 + digit;
            n /= 10;
        }
        return reverseNumber(result);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(swapNum(12345678 , 4, 5));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any class? what about convert number to char array, swap and parse it back?

```java
// helper function to convert char array to int
public static int parseInt(char[] chars) {
    int result = 0; // accumulator
    int idx_value = 1; // power of ten counter
    for (int i = chars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // loop from tail to head
        // char - '0' mean it will convert '0' to 0 and '1' will be 1 so on.
        result += (chars[i] - '0') * idx_value; 
        idx_value *= 10;
    }
    return result;
}

public static int swapNum(int n, int i, int j) {
    // convert number to char array
    char[] chars = ("" + n).toCharArray();
    // use zero based index
    i-=1;j-=1;
    // perform swap
    char temp = chars[i];
    chars[i] = chars[j];
    chars[j] = temp;
    // convert char array back to int
    return parseInt(chars);
}
```

Comment: i thought doing it that way but i can´t even use Strings or arrays, it's really by diving it and using only while or for loops :/